# VB6 data match a recordset current record to an Array and get description text

Tags: vba, vb6, recordset

I have table called beacons which has PrimaryCode, SecondaryCode and Description
I need to retrieve the full code from aonther table called data and split that code into Left$ and Right$ so that it matches the PrimaryCode and Secondary code, then I can get the Description. The full code is 000A0A003 so the left I capture 6 chars and the right I capture 3 chars from the Access current record to find a match in the array ABeacons.

I have tried this but no good

```
If IsEmpty(VcurrentRecord(0).VOBeaconCodePrimary) = False Then
    fullvalue = (VcurrentRecord(0).VOBeaconCodePrimary)
    leftvalue = Left$(VcurrentRecord(0).VOBeaconCodePrimary, 6)
    rightvalue = Right$(VcurrentRecord(0).VOBeaconCodePrimary, 3)

    If ABeacons(I).PrimaryCode = leftvalue Then
        'MsgBox ("found left value" & leftvalue)
        If leftvalue = ABeacons(I).PrimaryCode And rightvalue = ABeacons(I).SecondaryCode Then
            MsgBox (ABeacons(I).Description)
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: What is the issue?  An error?  No MsgBox?  I would suggest setting a break point and stepping through the code inspecting variables as you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to loop through the values in your `ABeacons` array to look for a match:

```
If IsEmpty(VcurrentRecord(0).VOBeaconCodePrimary) = False Then
    fullvalue = (VcurrentRecord(0).VOBeaconCodePrimary)
    leftvalue = Left$(VcurrentRecord(0).VOBeaconCodePrimary, 6)
    rightvalue = Right$(VcurrentRecord(0).VOBeaconCodePrimary, 3)

    Dim iCounter As Integer
    For iCounter = LBound(ABeacons) To UBound(ABeacons)
        If ABeacons(iCounter).PrimaryCode = leftvalue Then
            If leftvalue = ABeacons(iCounter).PrimaryCode And rightvalue = ABeacons(iCounter).SecondaryCode Then
                MsgBox(ABeacons(iCounter).Description)
            End If
        End If
    Next

End If
```

Comment: Your right, after a fresh coffee I can see my mistake, thanks

Comment: @ChrisR you could also consider using a Collection for your `ABeacons` array. You will be able to lookup items by key (your `PrimaryCode`) instead of looping through the array.